# Using outer() to map a vector of functions to a vector of inputs

Tags: r

I have a situation where I'd like to apply a vector of functions to a vector of inputs, and I am getting some bizarre outputs that I do not understand. Here is an example of what I mean:

```
library('purrr')
outer(c(1,2,3),c(sqrt,exp),FUN=map)
```

The output I expect is a 3x2 array

```
     [,1]        [,2]      
[1,] 1         2.718      
[2,] 1.414     7.389056   
[3,] 1.732     20.085537
```

corresponding to f(x) for each input x and function f. What I *actually* get is

```
     [,1]        [,2]       
[1,] 3814279     3814279    
[2,] 326845828   326845828  
[3,] 13438457698 13438457698
```

This output is completely bizarre and I have no idea how those numbers came to be!
I have tried Using sapply (or the other -apply functions) instead of map, for which I get this error

```
Error in get(as.character(FUN), mode = "function", envir = envir) : 
  object 'Y' of mode 'function' was not found
```

I have also tried using lists instead of vectors, which give me the same result. I'll accept any answer that either (a) shows me how to get the behavior I'm looking for or (b) explains where exactly those numbers come from. At this point, I've spent more time trying to figure this out than it would have taken to just solve my original problem with for loops, so I'm mostly posting out of stubborn curiosity.

This is my first time posting a programming related question on SO, so I apologize if anything is missing from my post. Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could explicitly use `mapply` in `outer` :

```
outer(c(1,2,3),c(sqrt,exp),function(x, y) mapply(function(p, q) q(p), x, y))

#         [,1]      [,2]
#[1,] 1.000000  2.718282
#[2,] 1.414214  7.389056
#[3,] 1.732051 20.085537
```

Or write a function and `Vectorize` it.

```
apply_fun <- function(x, y) y(x)
outer(c(1,2,3),c(sqrt,exp), Vectorize(apply_fun))
```

Comment: This works! Question: Why doesn't outer(c(1,2,3),c(sqrt,exp), function(p, q) q(p) ) work on it's own? why does it need the extra layers of function->mapply->function or be vectorized?

Comment: That is because `outer` passes all the values `c(1,2,3)` and `c(sqrt,exp)` together in the function and there is no vectorized way to apply different functions to same input. Put `outer(c(1,2,3),c(sqrt,exp), function(p, q) browser())` and check output of `p` and `q`.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a `do.call` solution:

```
sapply( c(sqrt,exp), 
        function(FUN) sapply( c(1,2,3), function(x) do.call(FUN,list(x))))

##         [,1]      [,2]
## [1,] 1.000000  2.718282
## [2,] 1.414214  7.389056
## [3,] 1.732051 20.085537
```